# Why does the Vaadin 20+ server take so long to start the webpack dev server?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, webpack-dev-server, vaadin-flow, vaadin20

Hi I want to update my actual Vaadin 8 Project into a Vaadin 20+ one. I configured under `src/main/resources/application.properties` the property `vaadin.whitelisted-packages=com/mycompany/myproject`.

Under `src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject` I have a `ClientApplication.java` class

```
package com.mycompany.myproject;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;

/**
 * Use the @PWA annotation make the application installable on phones, tablets
 * and some desktop browsers.
 */

@Theme(value = "mycompany")
@PWA(name = "My Company Fusion", shortName = "Company Fusion", offlineResources = { "images/logo.png" })
public class ClientApplication implements AppShellConfigurator {

}
```

Under `src/main/java/mycompany/server` I have the main Application.java class where the springboot app should start. And Under `src/main/java/mycompany` I have more than 4K java files which are also important and where I develop actively.

```
package mycompany.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.vaadin.artur.helpers.LaunchUtil;

import mycompany.server.core.MyConfigs;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 1. Load XML config file
        final boolean configRead = MyConfigs.readConfig();
        if (configRead) {
            System.out.println(MyConfigs.getBackendserverurl());
        }

        // TODO Helmer -> if debug, add prod
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        LaunchUtil.launchBrowserInDevelopmentMode(ctx);
    }

}
```

Every time I try to run `mvn -Dmaven.compiler.failOnError=false -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests spring-boot:run` the webpack server takes more than 10 minutes to start. sometimes it takes more than 30 mins.

Comment: Is there a specific step or line after which it takes a long time before continuing?
Are you behind a proxy that would affect some connections out?

Comment: Yes Im behind a proxy. The last step is `Vaadin application has been deployed and started to the context path "/".`

Comment: Can't come up with anything that would specifically run up the time that far.
Does the same happen if you use a clean project from start.vaadin.com ?

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist Im using the clean project from start.vaadin.com. The problems begins everytime when I add the 4K+ Java files to the project.

Comment: Do you have lots of dependencies in `package.json`? Also is this just a devMode issue or is webpack slow also when making a production build?

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist in package.json I only see the vaadin needed libs, that comes with the empty project. I didn't try to make a production build. This happens in devMode